# How to split each row of a DataFrame into 2 rows according to a rule?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame (stroll horizontally to the right to see all columns):

```
SIBT                SOBT                PLANNED_ARR_HOUR    PLANNED_DEP_HOUR    ARRIVAL_FLIGHT_HAUL  DEPARTURE_FLIGHT_HAUL
2016-01-01 04:05:00 2016-01-01 14:10:00 4                   14                  Ultra Long Haul      Long Haul
2016-01-01 04:25:00 2016-01-01 06:30:00 4                   6                   Ultra Long Haul      Short Haul
2016-01-01 05:05:00 2016-01-01 07:05:00 5                   7                   Long Haul            Long Haul
2016-01-01 05:20:00 2016-01-01 10:40:00 5                   10                  Short Haul           Long Haul
2016-01-01 05:25:00 2016-01-01 10:50:00 5                   10                  Long Haul            Long Haul
```

I need to merge columns `SIBT` and `SOBT`, `PLANNED_ARR_HOUR` and `PLANNED_DEP_HOUR`, `ARRIVAL_FLIGHT_HAUL` and `DEPARTURE_FLIGHT_HAUL` in order to get a new DataFrame as follows:

```
DATETIME             PLANNER_HOUR     FLIGHT_HAUL       TYPE
2016-01-01 04:05:00  4                Ultra Long Haul   ARR
2016-01-01 14:10:00  14               Long Haul         DEP
2016-01-01 04:25:00  4                Ultra Long Haul   ARR
2016-01-01 06:30:00  6                Short Haul        DEP
...
```

Basically, each row should be split into two rows in order to get arrivals (ARR) and departures (DEP).

- `SIBT`, `PLANNED_ARR_HOUR` and `ARRIVAL_FLIGHT_HAUL` refer to the type ARR (arrivals).
- `SOBT`, `PLANNED_DEP_HOUR` and `DEPARTURE_FLIGHT_HAUL` refer to the type DEP (departures).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest approach would be to extract the arrivals and departures from your original table by column, rename the columns and recombine. For example

```
arrive = data[ ['SIBT', 'PLANNED_ARR_HOUR', 'ARRIVAL_FLIGHT_HAUL'] ]
depart = data[ ['SOBT', 'PLANNED_DEP_HOUR', 'DEPARTURE_FLIGHT_HAUL'] ]
```

You now have 2 dataframes with the relevant columns, change the column names of *both* dataframes to your desired output.

```
arrive.columns = ['DATETIME', 'PLANNER_HOUR', 'FLIGHT_HAUL']
depart.columns = ['DATETIME', 'PLANNER_HOUR', 'FLIGHT_HAUL']
```

Add your type column.

```
arrive['TYPE'] = 'ARR'
depart['TYPE'] = 'DEP'
```

Now they have the same column names they can be concatenated as normal.

```
result = pd.concat([arrive, depart])
```

Comment: Snap! But I used `data[ ['SIBT', 'PLANNED_ARR_HOUR', 'ARRIVAL_FLIGHT_HAUL'] ].copy()` to avoid the `SettingWithCopyWarning`. Not necessary in this case but maybe better practice (or maybe it's just my OCD!)

Answer (score 4):

Easiest is to split into two and then concat:

```
dep_cols = ['SOBT', 'PLANNED_DEP_HOUR', 'DEPARTURE_FLIGHT_HAUL']
arr_cols = ['SIBT', 'PLANNED_ARR_HOUR', 'ARRIVAL_FLIGHT_HAUL']
new_cols = ['DATETIME','PLANNER_HOUR','FLIGHT_HAUL']

dep = df[dep_cols].copy()
arr = df[arr_cols].copy()

dep.columns, arr.columns = new_cols, new_cols

dep['TYPE'] = 'DEP'
arr['TYPE'] = 'ARR'

pd.concat([dep, arr])

    DATETIME    PLANNER_HOUR    FLIGHT_HAUL     TYPE
0   2016-01-01 14:10:00     14  Long Haul       DEP
1   2016-01-01 06:30:00     6   Short Haul      DEP
2   2016-01-01 07:05:00     7   Long Haul       DEP
3   2016-01-01 10:40:00     10  Long Haul       DEP
4   2016-01-01 10:50:00     10  Long Haul       DEP
0   2016-01-01 04:05:00     4   Ultra Long Haul ARR
1   2016-01-01 04:25:00     4   Ultra Long Haul ARR
2   2016-01-01 05:05:00     5   Long Haul       ARR
3   2016-01-01 05:20:00     5   Short Haul      ARR
4   2016-01-01 05:25:00     5   Long Haul       ARR
```

Answer (score 0):

First `rename` columns by dictionary created by `zip`, add new column by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and for avoid duplicated index add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
c1 = ['SIBT', 'PLANNED_ARR_HOUR', 'ARRIVAL_FLIGHT_HAUL']
c2 = ['SOBT', 'PLANNED_DEP_HOUR', 'DEPARTURE_FLIGHT_HAUL']
c3 = ['DATETIME','PLANNER_HOUR','FLIGHT_HAUL']

df1 = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(c1, c3)))[c3].assign(TYPE='ARR')
df2 = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(c2, c3)))[c3].assign(TYPE='DEP')
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
              DATETIME  PLANNER_HOUR      FLIGHT_HAUL TYPE
0  2016-01-01 04:05:00             4  Ultra Long Haul  ARR
1  2016-01-01 14:10:00            14        Long Haul  DEP
2  2016-01-01 04:25:00             4  Ultra Long Haul  ARR
3  2016-01-01 06:30:00             6       Short Haul  DEP
4  2016-01-01 05:05:00             5        Long Haul  ARR
5  2016-01-01 07:05:00             7        Long Haul  DEP
6  2016-01-01 05:20:00             5       Short Haul  ARR
7  2016-01-01 10:40:00            10        Long Haul  DEP
8  2016-01-01 05:25:00             5        Long Haul  ARR
9  2016-01-01 10:50:00            10        Long Haul  DEP
```

Another solution with `lreshape`:

```
df = df.assign(TYPE1='ARR', TYPE2='DEP')
d = {'DATETIME':['SIBT','SOBT'],
     'PLANNER_HOUR':['PLANNED_ARR_HOUR','PLANNED_DEP_HOUR'],
     'FLIGHT_HAUL':['ARRIVAL_FLIGHT_HAUL','DEPARTURE_FLIGHT_HAUL'],
     'TYPE':['TYPE1','TYPE2']}
df = pd.lreshape(df, d)
print (df)
              DATETIME  PLANNER_HOUR      FLIGHT_HAUL TYPE
0  2016-01-01 04:05:00             4  Ultra Long Haul  ARR
1  2016-01-01 04:25:00             4  Ultra Long Haul  ARR
2  2016-01-01 05:05:00             5        Long Haul  ARR
3  2016-01-01 05:20:00             5       Short Haul  ARR
4  2016-01-01 05:25:00             5        Long Haul  ARR
5  2016-01-01 14:10:00            14        Long Haul  DEP
6  2016-01-01 06:30:00             6       Short Haul  DEP
7  2016-01-01 07:05:00             7        Long Haul  DEP
8  2016-01-01 10:40:00            10        Long Haul  DEP
9  2016-01-01 10:50:00            10        Long Haul  DEP
```